# Как спрятать текст при наведении на изображение?

Tags: html, css, hover

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать даное действие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.block{
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
}
.block img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.block_title{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block:hover .block_title{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg" alt="">
<div class="block_title">Надпись на картинке</div>
</div>
```